# XPages: how to convert all pass-through rich text in a Notes document to HTML

Tags: html, xpages, lotus-notes

I have this Notes document, maintained in Notes but displayed in a browser through XPages. The document contains a rich-text field. The rich-text contains some pass-thru HTML (< h r > for example, it works), but it also contains an iframe that is somehow filtered out.

Does anyone know more about this, to be more specific: does anyone know how to set XPages to produce **all** pass-thru HTML?

Comment: Is your question how to extract only the passthough html from a RT field and display it in XPages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the problem is the filtering of the iframe then just set the property htmlFilter of your richtext control to "identity". That switches off all content filtering.

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"
                    value="#{document1.postBody}" htmlFilter="identity"
                    htmlFilterIn="identity">
</xp:inputRichText>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Recht vielen Dank!! Now how on Earth is one supposed to know that the identity option does this, and what the htmlFilter property does in the first place? Ok, once you know what to look for...

Comment: Checked again using Google: only SEVEN pages that match the query _"xpages" "htmlfilter" browser "identity" "iframe"_  ... It wouldn't strike me as odd if I were to find an 8th page tomorrow, in your blog... (nur eine Idee)

Comment: You can find a good description about filtering and this property in book "XPages Mastering XPages Second Edition" in Chapter 21 at "Active Content Filtering" page 1061-1066.

Comment: Agree, had to ask this up years ago when I wanted to paste a Youtube embed code into my content. But Knut is right: this book has answers to almost everything XPages related

Comment: Please keep in mind that filtering is a security feature. Disabling the filter can lead to security issues like XSS.